# How to tell the user the number of correct answers in a quiz

Tags: ruby

I made a simple quiz, and would like to know how to inform the user the number of correct, and if possible incorrect, answers they got at the end of the quiz. Below is my code.

```
prompt = "> "
puts "Planet Pop Quiz, is the Earth round?"
print prompt

while user_input = gets.chomp
  case user_input
  when "yes"
    puts "Correct!"
    break 
  when "no"
    puts "Wrong!"
    break 
  else
    puts "Please answer either yes or no"
    print prompt 
  end
end

prompt = "> "
puts "Is Pluto close to the sun?"
print prompt

while user_input = gets.chomp 
  case user_input
  when "yes"
    puts "Wrong!"
    break 
  when "no"
    puts "Correct!"
    break 
  else
    puts "Please answer either yes or no"
    print prompt 
  end
end

prompt = "> "
puts "Is Mercury bigger than Jupiter?"
print prompt

while user_input = gets.chomp 
  case user_input
  when "yes"
    puts "Wrong!"
    break 
  when "no"
    puts "Correct!"
    break 
  else
    puts "Please answer either yes or no"
    print prompt 
  end
end
```

Comment: To simplify, wrap in `loop do ...` with `case gets.chomp`. You already `break` out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Start by declaring two variables at the top of your code:

```
correct = 0
incorrect = 0
```

Then for each switch statement, add `correct += 1` and `incorrect += 1` to the respective `when` sections.

By the end of your code you should be able to output:

```
puts "You got #{correct} answers correct and #{incorrect} answers wrong."
```

Variable assignments and string interpolations are very simple. I recommend you [go here](http://ruby-doc.org/) and follow the links under "Getting Started".

Comment: Thank you very much sjagr, this was very helpful and simple!  Greatly appreciate your time and expertise!

Answer (score 0):

You could put your questions in an array so that you can remove the duplicate code of asking user response, and in the process keep counters of right and wrong answers.  Here is one way to do that:

```
prompt = "> "

quiz = [
    {q: "Is the Earth round?", a: "yes"},
    {q: "Is Pluto close to the sun?", a: "yes"}
]

result = {:right => 0, :wrong => 0}

puts "Planet Pop Quiz:"

quiz.each.with_index do |h, i|
    puts "Q#{i+1}: #{h[:q]}"
    print prompt

    while user_input = gets.chomp
        case user_input
            when "yes", "no"
                if user_input == h[:a]
                    puts "Correct!" 
                    result[:right] += 1
                else
                    puts "Wrong!"
                    result[:wrong] += 1
                end
                break;
            else
                puts "Please answer either yes or no"
                print prompt 
        end
    end
end

print "You answered #{result[:right]} questions correctly out of #{questions.size} questions"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Wand Maker!  I need to study this a bit but looks like I will learn some new things from your advice.  Thank you for your time and expertise!

Answer (score 0):

The one thing worth absorbing first when writing Ruby code is learning to structure your problem more in terms of *data manipulation* and less in terms of *code*.

For example:

```
# Define your questions in an array-of-arrays
@questions = [
  [ 'Is Mars a planet?', 'yes' ],
  [ 'Is the Sun a star?', 'yes' ],
  [ 'Is Pluto a planet?', 'maybe' ]
]
@answers = [ 'yes', 'no', 'maybe' ]
@responses = [ ]
```

Then you can iterate over these easily:

```
@questions.each do |question, answer|
   puts question

   loop do
     response = line.gets.chomp.downcase

     if (@answers.include?(response))
       @responses << response
       break
     else
       puts "Please respond with one of: #{@answers.join(', ')}"
     end
   end
 end

 # Keep score by true or false on answer matching
 @score = { true: 0, false: 0 }

 # Now step over each response and tally up score
 # according to the expected answer.
 @responses.each_with_index do |response, i|
   @score[response == @questions[i][1])] += 1
 end

 puts "You got %d correct and %d incorrect" % [ 
   @score[true],
   @score[false]
 ]
```

Note that here you can manipulate the various parameters without having to actually change any of the code. This allows a great deal of flexibility, and provides simple paths to expand on this functionality. For example, you can easily read the questions in from a JSON or YAML file.

Comment: Thank  you tadman!  This is very helpful information, I need to do my homework and practice a bit more.  Thank you for your time and expertise!